# android database triggers not work properly

Tags: android, sqlite, triggers

i have a sqlite database file which has some triggers

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_number_1 AFTER INSERT ON table1 BEGIN  UPDATE table2 SET    date = 0,     address=new.address,    number=new.address ; END
```

... according to this triggers, when i insert a new row on table1, the table2 should be updated.... but it doesn't happen in some cases and `-journal` file will be removed ... where is my mistake?... my inserting method is wrong or there is other problem with that??.... thanks...

Comment: Works for me, but your description is unclear. Show some example data and the desired result.

Comment: checkout this example for trigger demo http://code2concept.blogspot.in/2015/02/android-sqlite-trigger-demo.html